# How to prevent the terminal from closing when the program it was started with ends?

Tags: command-line, terminal, tmux, gnome-terminal, top

If I start a terminal (any terminal, for example urxvt) like `urxvt -e sleep 5`, then a new terminal is launched but after 5 seconds the terminal closes, because the `sleep` program has ended. How can I start a terminal with a program on the command line, but have the terminal stay alive after that process has ended?

In practice, what I'd actually like to do is `urxvt -e tmux new-session top`, which opens urxvt with a tmux session that is running `top`. But when I press `q`, `top` ends which also causes tmux and urxvt to end as well. I'd like when I exit `top` for me to be taken to a shell within tmux.

Comment: Not a duplicate. That post has to do with keeping the process alive when the terminal exits. I'm asking about keeping the terminal (and tmux) alive when the process exits.

Comment: It strikes me that `urxvt -e sleep 5 and a shell please` would be better implemented as `( sleep 5 && urxvt ) &`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The terminal (tmux) closes when it's executed the command you told it to execute. If you want to execute `top` and then an interactive shell, you need to tell it to do that. Combining commands is the job of the shell, so run an intermediate shell (which isn't interactive) and tell *it* to run the two commands in succession.

```
urxvt -e tmux new-session sh -c 'top; "$SHELL"'
```

Answer (score 0):

One possibility:

```
gnome-terminal -e sh -c "sleep 5; bash"
```

The point is to run the shell (`bash` in this case) after your initial command will finish. Unfortunately simple `gnome-terminal -e 'sleep 5; bash'` is not possible because the whole sentence `sleep 5; bash` is interpreted as one command.

Comment: urxvt doesn't seem to start for me when the `-e` flag contains something in quotes. So nothing  even launches for me. `urxvt -e 'sleep 3'` doesn't launch any urxvt, but `urxvt -e sleep 3` does.

Comment: @user779159 I've tested on gnome-terminal and it works. I will try urxvt later on.

Comment: `rxvt -e` takes a list of arguments: the command to run and its arguments. Gnome-terminal supports this but for some reason they renamed the option to `-x` and used a different semantics for `-e`.